# Need to check whether user input is a number. Code is not working as intended. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers, prompt

Just need to check that data user input on prompt is a number in Javascript

```
  var userAge = prompt("Please enter your age", "");
    if (typeof userAge == 'number') {
      document.write("You are " + userAge + " years old.");
    } else {
      document.write('Please enter a valid number');
    }
```

When I type my age, 28, to test, I expect that "You are 28 years old." will be printed to the document. However, it prints the else part of the code: "Please enter a valid number."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value from `prompt` is a `string`. Use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead:

```js
var userAge = prompt("Please enter your age", "");
if (isNaN(userAge)) {
  document.write('Please enter a valid number');
} else {
  document.write("You are " + userAge + " years old.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any number or value enclosed by a single or double quote in JavaScript is treated as a string, for that reason, `typeof userAge` is equal to `'string'`.

Use this code instead:

```
var userAge = prompt("Please enter your age", "");

if (/^\d+[.]?\d+$/.test(userAge)) {
  document.write("You are " + userAge + " years old.");

} else {
  document.write('Please enter a valid number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to a number with [`Number.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt), then use [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) like so:

```js
var userAge = parseInt(prompt("Please enter your age"));
if (isNaN(userAge)) {
  document.write('Please enter a valid number');
} else {
  document.write("You are " + userAge + " years old.");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `parseInt` as `isNaN` does the type coercion. Also it's not very good to copy-paste other peoples' answers.

Comment: I didn't mean to @KoshVery but our answers are the same because the solution was the same. Also I didn't copy your answer.